# [jQuery/javascript]: find a couple of items (2) in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 10 rows of numbers, each row has 5 number separated by a dot, like so:

[image]

All of those are in a row with the same class name.

I now have to find in each row if they amount to 90 summed together.

So if the first row contains "2" and "88" (in any sequence) they get highlighted (the numbers, not the row). Same with the second row, third and so forth.

The purpose is to find 2 numbers that summed make a total of 90 (an only two, not 3 or more).

I'm currently at this:

```
function CheckAndHighlight(className){
      var numebrsTd = $("td[class*="+className+"]");
      var numbers = numebrsTd.html().split('.');

      for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
          {
            var numI=parseInt(numbers[i],10);
            for(var j=0;j<numbers.length;j++)
              {
                  var numJ=parseInt(numbers[j],10);

                  // Avoid summing up numbers at same index
                  if(i==j) continue;

                  // Check if two numbers sum up to 90
                  if(numI+numJ == 90)
                    {
                      // Clear the row
                      numebrsTd.html('');

                      // Loop through all IP numbers of the row
                      for(var k=0;k<numbers.length;k++)
                        {
                          var numK=parseInt(numbers[k],10);
                          // Create span with th number
                          var span = $('<span>'+numK+'</span>')
                          // Check the index with index of numbers to be highlighted
                          var highlight = k == i || k == j;
                          // Add class to the span if to highlight
                          if(highlight) span.addClass('highlight');
                          // add '.' at the end of number if not last one
                          if(k<numbers.length) span.append('.');
                          // Add new Span to the row
                          numebrsTd.append(span);
                        }

                      return;                  
                    }
              }
          }
    }
```

See the current work: http://lt.mrweb.info/

I need to make the function to work just by calling it `CheckAndHighlight('bari')` or `CheckAndHighlight('cagliari')`

Comment: How is your question relevant to jQuery? It's just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

The following code works as follow:

1. Loop through All IP rows
2. Extract IP numbers from the row Splitted by '.'
3. Starting from First number try summing up with rest of numbers one by one to check for 90
4. If two numbers make sum of 90 then Highlight those numbers by using Their Index in the IP row and get out of the Loop

```js
function ProcessRowsWithClass(className)
{
   $('td[class*='+className+']').each(function(){
    CheckAndHighlight($(this))
  });
}

function CheckAndHighlight(numebrsTd)
{
  var numbers = numebrsTd.html().split('.');
  for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
      {
        var numI=parseInt(numbers[i],10);
        for(var j=0;j<numbers.length;j++)
          {
              var numJ=parseInt(numbers[j],10);
              
              // Avoid summing up numbers at same index
              if(i==j) continue;
            
              // Check if two numbers sum up to 90
              if(numI+numJ == 90)
                {
                  // Clear the row
                  numebrsTd.html('');
                  
                  // Loop through all IP numbers of the row
                  for(var k=0;k<numbers.length;k++)
                    {
                      var numK=parseInt(numbers[k],10);
                      // Create span with th number
                      var span = $('<span>'+numK+'</span>')
                      // Check the index with index of numbers to be highlighted
                      var highlight = k == i || k == j;
                      // Add class to the span if to highlight
                      if(highlight) span.addClass('highlight');
                      // add '.' at the end of number if not last one
                      if(k<numbers.length) span.append('.');
                      // Add new Span to the row
                      numebrsTd.append(span);
                    }
                  
                  return;                  
                }
          }
      }
}

ProcessRowsWithClass('genova');
ProcessRowsWithClass('bari');
ProcessRowsWithClass('cagliari');
```

```css
span.highlight{
  color:green;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Bari</h1>
<table>
<tr><td class="bari1">80.10.86.30.65</td></tr>
<tr><td class="bari2">96.11.73.36.13</td></tr>
<tr><td class="bari3">78.34.50.72.40</td></tr>
<tr><td class="bari4">34.78.69.60.22</td></tr>
<tr><td class="bari5">12.29.30.69.33</td></tr>
<tr><td class="bari6">70.10.20.70.44</td></tr>

</table>
<h1>Cagliari</h1>
<table>
<tr><td class="cagliari1">80.10.86.30.65</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cagliari2">96.11.73.36.13</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cagliari3">78.34.50.72.40</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cagliari4">34.78.69.60.22</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cagliari5">12.29.30.69.33</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cagliari6">70.10.20.70.44</td></tr>

</table>

<h1>Genova</h1>
<table>

<tr><td class="genova1">80.10.86.30.65</td></tr>
<tr><td class="genova2">96.11.73.36.13</td></tr>
<tr><td class="genova3">78.34.50.72.40</td></tr>
<tr><td class="genova4">34.78.69.60.22</td></tr>
<tr><td class="genova5">12.29.30.69.33</td></tr>
<tr><td class="genova6">70.10.20.70.44</td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your rows into numbers to check if any two of them can make your target sum of 90. The following example outputs "1.34.5.89.1" and "3.47.12.43.3" out of the five rows given:

```js
var rows = [
        '1.2.23.34.5',
        '1.34.5.89.1',
        '75.44.5.89.5',
        '5.3.2.55.6',
        '3.47.12.43.3'
    ],
    check = function(row, target) {
        row = row.split('.');
        var i = 0,
            j,
            l = row.length;
        for (; i < l-1; i++) {
            for (j = i+1; j < l; j++) {
                if (parseInt(row[i], 10) + parseInt(row[j], 10) === target) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    i = 0,
    target = 90;
for (; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (check(rows[i], target)) {
        console.log(rows[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks! Pls see my edit. (ps: the snippet is not working)